# Why does corda node emits ActiveMQ thread error?

Tags: corda, activemq-artemis, cordite

I am trying to run just notary node for example with cordite network map service. After notary node starts I am getting the following errors continuously. Can anyone let know what can be the cause of these errors.

> [INFO ] 2018-10-11T05:21:37,365 [main] RPCServer - Starting RPC server with configuration RPCServerConfiguration(rpcThreadPoolSize=1, reapInterval=PT1S, deduplicationCacheExpiry=PT24H)
>
> [ERROR] 2018-10-11T05:25:58,805 [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-scheduled-threads)] server - AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred.
>
> [ERROR] 2018-10-11T05:26:18,805 [Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-scheduled-threads)] server - AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred.
>
> [ERROR] 2018-10-11T05:26:38,802 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-scheduled-threads)] server - AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred.

Comment: Is this causing any issues? Or is it just noise in the logs?

Comment: It's not causing any issues.

Comment: This can be ignored. Hopefully a future version of Corda will suppress these harmless messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error indicates that something on the network is connecting to the ActiveMQ Artemis broker, but it's not completing any protocol handshake. This is commonly seen with, for example, load balancers that do a health check by creating a socket connection without sending any real data just to see if the port is open on the target machine.

Comment: Makes sense. I have liveliness probe in kubernetes pod.